# Find the limit of rational function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have this rational function

$
\lim_{x \to2} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}\sqrt{x+7}-2\sqrt{x+7}-3\sqrt{x+2}+6}{x\sqrt{4x+1}-2\sqrt{4x+1}-3x+6}
$

And i really don't know where to start to solve it.
So if you can give me some tips on solving this i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:let $\sqrt{x+2}=a,\sqrt{x+7}=b$ and $\sqrt{4x+1}=c$

$
\lim_{x \to2} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}\sqrt{x+7}-2\sqrt{x+7}-3\sqrt{x+2}+6}{x\sqrt{4x+1}-2\sqrt{4x+1}-3x+6}=\lim_{x \to2}\frac{(a-2)(b-3)}{(x-2)(c-3)}
$

Do you know what to do now?

Comment: I know now what to do, but can you please explain where did number 6 go?

Comment: Note that (a-2)(b-3)=ab-2b-3a+6